# Chrome 75 regexp, 'S' matches strange unicode range

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

We have a strange bug on the latest version of Chrome (75) that replace `S` to `&#83;`

```js
console.log(
  'AZERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLMWXCVBN'.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>&]/gim, char => `&#${char.charCodeAt(0)};`)
)
```

`//AZERTYUIOPQ&#83;DFGHJKLMWXCVBN`

Do someone have any idea if the code is the problem or Chrome is the problem?

Comment: String.fromCharCode(83) is an S btw

Comment: I was running v74 and there was no problem, updated to v75 and see the issue now

Comment: I just upgraded my Chrome and I see the same behavior.

Comment: FYI, it only happens when you use the `i` modifier.

Comment: It is triggered when the end of the range changes from `\u017E` to `\u017F`. That happens to be the Latin Small Letter Long S code.

Comment: There must be another Unicode character that's considered a case-insensitive equivalent of `S`.

Comment: Why *are* you using the `i` and `m` flags? Also, hex 9999 is a weird place to end a range.

Comment: It's very weird, it doesn't happen if the range is `[\u017E-\u017F]`

Comment: https://crrev.com/647490

Comment: It happens with the minimum range of `'S'.match(/[\u0178-\u017F]/i)` very weird indeed.

Comment: Wow, that’s a weird bug. Caused by kind of optimization about the way to match a character range? If you add the `/u` flag it behaves normally.

Comment: They might have just caught this - [Commit - Fix character ranges in case insensitive regexp](https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/9bcacf60f817004b6c7d400a89dd829f2b9505f9)

Comment: Why are even you using the i and m flags in that interval?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed in 75.0.3770.142.

---

You have found an interesting bug:

These two tests are true for some reason that hinges on the unrelated character range:

```
> /[\u0178-\u017F]/i.test('s')
true
> /[\u0178-\u017F]/i.test('S')
true
```

Introduced by https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/v8/v8/+/1478710 (April).

The fix in https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/v8/v8/+/1648098 seems related, but Canary 77.0.3818.0 with v8 7.7.27 still exhibits this behavior. This is a separate bug: https://crbug.com/971636

The bug that introduced the issue (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=8348) discusses how ECMAScript treats `i` and `u` differently:

- `i` alone calls `toUpperCase`, which uses case *mapping*
- `iu` invokes Unicode case *folding*

These are slightly different (this bug notwithstanding).

I also found what seems to be a different bug:

Here's a small test case, although the fix in v8 refers to Turkish case folding:

```
> text='ſ';
"ſ"
> new RegExp(text, 'i').test(text.toUpperCase())
true
> new RegExp(text, 'i').test('S')
false
```

It was introduced in the same revision, but it isn't quite the same bug — it's *specific* to the ſ character, whose uppercase version lies in the ASCII range and therefore triggers a different code path in V8's regexp compiler. Fixed separately at https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/v8/v8/+/1827683

Answer (score 0):

Changing to:

```
'S'.replace(/[\u00A0-\u017E\u0180-\u9999<>&]/gim, char => `&#${char.charCodeAt(0)};`)
```

will avoid the Unicode character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER LONG S' which is `\u017F`. This is only a workaround.

The other end of the triggering range seems to be `\u0073` which is 'LATIN SMALL LETTER S'.

Answer (score 0):

The flags `i` and `m` aren't even used in that interval & you need to use the flag `u`
which treats pattern as a sequence of Unicode code points.

```js
console.log(
  'AZERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLMWXCVBN'.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>&]/gu, char => `&#${char.charCodeAt(0)};`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same issue in Chrome 75, but not Chrome 74. The issue was fixed by using the following regular expression:

```
'AZERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLMWXCVBN'.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>&]/g, char => `&#${char.charCodeAt(0)};`)
```

As mentioned in some of the comments, I don't believe you need i,u, or m modifiers.