# Chrome regular expression matches character it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html-entities

I've used this code to convert certain characters to HTML entities:

```js
var rawStr = 'https://foobars.com';

var encodedStr = rawStr.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
  return '&#' + i.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
});

console.log(encodedStr);
```

This also converts the letter "s", but only in Chrome (75.0.3770.100, Windows 10), not other browsers. [Here's a Regex101 sample](https://regex101.com/r/6nd5xn/4) showing the same odd behaviour:

[image]

Why does this happen, and why only in Chrome?

Comment: @VLAZ As far as I can tell, Pill's computer/browser converts a regular ASCII 115 `s` for some reason. We cannot replicate this, but it's not some other Unicode character that just happens to look like an `s`.

Comment: @deceze I checked between my browsers and this problem (on regex101.com) only occures in my chrome webbrowser (Chrome Version 75.0.3770.100). I am on Windows 10. Could you guys check out Chris G link in chrome and see if you have the same problem there?

Comment: Damn, Chrome does indeed match the `s`! What the hell?

Comment: According to my logs this error begun on june the 7th 2019. So perhaps chrome released some update or wathever that broke the code. Anyway, removing the i from /gim solves it for me.

Comment: My guess would be that the `i` flag causes it to match 's' as the lower case version of some normalised Unicode character like 'Ś' or so. No idea whether that's considered the correct behaviour or not. May be worth reporting to the Chrome team.

Comment: It seems to trigger on unicode character [LATIN SMALL LETTER LONG S](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/17f/index.htm) (U+017F); using regex `[\u0180-\u9999]` doesn't trigger it, where `[\u017F-\u9999]` does. But it gets stranger: it doesn't match on `[\u017F]` alone. In fact, it doesn't match for the range `[\u017F-\u039B]`, but _does_ match for the range `[\u017F-\u039C]` and beyond...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56499440/chrome-75-regexp-s-matches-strange-unicode-range

Comment: The bug: https://crbug.com/971636

Comment: Fixed in 75.0.3770.142.